# Pasar valor seleccionado de Select a variable php

Tags: php, mysql, post, get

Estoy haciendo un CRUD con php, ya logro insertar datos y ahora quiero modificarlos utilizando una clase que recibe los datos seleccionados de varios input. Pero por alguna razón NO ME DEVUELVE LO SELECCIONADO POR LOS SELECTBOX solo los INPUT TEXT.

Alguna sugerencia???

```
 <?php
 $consulta=Consultar($_GET['id_registro']);
 function Consultar($id_registro)
{
include 'conexion.php';
$sentencia="SELECT * FROM registros_delincuentes WHERE 
id_registro='".$id_registro."' ";
$resultado= $mysqli->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al consultar 
registro.".mysqli_error($mysqli));
$row=$resultado->fetch_assoc();
return [
  $row['apellido_paterno'],
  $row['apellido_materno'],
  $row['nombre'],
  $row['nacionalidad'],
  $row['grupo_sanguineo']];
  ?>

 <form action="modificarDos.php" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="id_registro" value="<?php echo 
 $_GET['id_registro']?> ">

 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="APELLIDO PATERNO" 
 id="apellido_P" name="apellido_P" value="<?php echo $consulta[0] ?>">

 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="APELLIDO MATERNO" 
 id="apellido_M" name="apellido_M" value="<?php echo $consulta[1] ?>">

 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="NOMBRE(S)" id="nombre" 
 name="nombre" value="<?php echo $consulta[2] ?>">

 <select name="grupoS" id="grupoS" class='form-control' value=" 
 <?php echo $consulta[3] ?>"> //-------------No me regresa lo seleccionado
    <option value="">SELECCIONE:</option>
    <option value="1">O POSITIVO</option>
    <option value="2">O NEGATIVO</option>
 </select>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">ACTUALIZAR</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podría ser que estés accediendo a un dato que no toca, ya que por lo que veo el grupo sanguíneo esta en la posición 4 del array, en la 3 tienes la nacionalidad, la cual no está en el formulario.
A parte de eso, ten cuidado porque no estás cerrando la función antes de cerrar el código php.

Comment: Tienes razón, lo quise editar para sintetizarlo aquí pero ya he colocado los $row en orden y me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Puedes usar la función var_dump() para ver el contenido de la variable $consulta y editar la pregunta mostrando el resultado? Más que nada para asegurarnos de que los datos llegan al array.

Answer (score 1):

Veo varias cosas en tu código.

1. El método del formulario es `POST`, entonces usa `$_POST` para obtener los datos. Además, somete el dato esencial a un control, para que el código no siga adelante si ese dato no está presente.
2. En las instrucciones SQL, no hay que poner comillas simples en las columnas numéricas. Supongo que `id_registro` es una columna numérica
3. Deberías controlar si la consulta trae filas o no, porque podría venir vacía si el criterio no se cumple
4. Hace falta dar coherencia al código, retornando siempre un array, sea con los datos, sea con una clave `error` dentro que sirva para verificar consistentemente el resultado. El uso de `die` no ayuda mucho, porque abandonas el código a su suerte, pudiendo tener, según que contexto de uso, un comportamiento no deseado.

Aplicando todo esto, podrías hacer algo así:

```
#Comprobamos si se pasó el post y lo guardamos en una variable
$mID = !( empty($_POST["id_registro"]) ) ? $_POST["id_registro"] : NULL;
if ($mID) 
{
    $mData=Consultar($mID);
} else {
    $mData=array("error"=>"No se posteó dato para id_registro");     
}
#Usar $mData buscando por ejemplo si hay clave error o no
if (array_key_exists('error', $mData)) {
    echo $mData["error"];
} else {
    #Usar $mData para sacar los datos extraídos de la base de datos
}

# Función  -------------------------- 
function Consultar($mID)
{
    $mData=array();
    include "conexion.php";
    $sql="SELECT * FROM registros_delincuentes WHERE id_registro=$mID";
    $rs=$mysqli->query($sql);       
    if ($rs) 
    {
        if ($rs->num_rows !== 0) {          
            $row=$rs->fetch_assoc();
            $mData[]=$row;
        } else {
            $mData["error"]="No hay registros con ID: $mID";
        }
    } else {
        $mData["error"]="Error al consultar registro: {$mysqli->error}";
    }
    return $mData;      
}
```

> ### Nota sobre la seguridad
>
> Tu consulta SQL es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Es un
>   grave riesgo que podría afectar no solamente a la base de datos, sino
>   a todo el sistema. Considera el uso de consultas preparadas para
>   prevenir ese riesgo.